# How to purge an already dropped table?

Tags: oracle

I dropped a table but didn't purge it. How can I purge it, so I can release the tablespace that the table uses?

Comment: check this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9018.htm)

Answer (score 4):

```
PURGE TABLE test;
```

or

```
PURGE RECYCLEBIN;
```

From docs:

> The following statement removes the table test from the recycle bin.
>   If more than one version of test resides in the recycle bin, Oracle
>   Database removes the version that has been there the longest:
>
> ```
> PURGE TABLE test;
> ```
>
> To determine system-generated name of the table you want removed from
>   your recycle bin, issue a SELECT statement on your recycle bin. Using
>   that object name, you can remove the table by issuing a statement
>   similar to the following statement. (The system-generated name will
>   differ from the one shown in the example.)
>
> ```
> PURGE TABLE RB$$33750$TABLE$0;
> ```
>
> Remove the Contents of Your Recycle Bin:
>
> Example  To remove the entire contents of your recycle bin, issue
>   the following statement:
>
> ```
> PURGE RECYCLEBIN;
> ```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9018.htm

Answer (score 3):

The syntax is:

```
PURGE TABLE table_name;
```

For example,

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t(a NUMBER);

Table created.

SQL> DROP TABLE t;

Table dropped.
```

Let's check the **recyclebin** content:

```
SQL> SHOW  RECYCLEBIN
ORIGINAL NAME    RECYCLEBIN NAME                OBJECT TYPE  DROP TIME
---------------- ------------------------------ ------------ -------------------
T                BIN$aLV3XomoSPCRkJ8yZfos7w==$0 TABLE        2015-11-26:13:43:27
```

Let's **PURGE** the table from recyclebin:

```
SQL> PURGE TABLE t;

Table purged.

SQL> SHOW  RECYCLEBIN
SQL>
```

it is now purged from recyclebin.

Answer (score 1):

The following statement can be used to purge the table from the recycle bin.

```
PURGE TABLE tablename;
```

for further reference check this [Link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9018.htm)